# Set default value for a input file form

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamically set value of a file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

I have an input file HTML form and I want to set the initial value for the file path in an HTML form . I try to change tag "value" but it doesn't work anyway.
 `<input type="file" name="testcase" value= "C:\test.txt">`

Please give me some advice for this small problem. Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input

Comment: I did a full referenced and up-to date (dec 2013) answer about this here: [Remember and Repopulate File Input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20537822/588079)

Comment: The "answer trail" created for this question by various moderators led me astray.  The "Possible Duplicate" for this question, "Dynamically set value of a file input," while related, isn't the same question.  *That* question is in turn marked as a duplicate of "How to set file input value when dropping file on page?" which certainly is a different question than this one.  I agree: reopen.  Since I can't answer this question because it's closed, and I'm out of characters in this comment, I'm leaving my answer as my next comment.

Comment: *Comment used as answer because the question is closed so I can't answer it:* Generally you can't set an initial value to `<input type="file">` for security reasons as explained below.  But you can set a "filter" to control which files are shown in the user's selection window via the `accept` option to `<input>`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file for details.

Answer (score 39):

From [HTMLHelp.com](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/input.html) :

> The file input type creates a field
>   through which users can upload files
>   from their local computer or network.
>   The VALUE attribute specifies the name
>   of the initial file, but it is
>   typically ignored by browsers as a
>   security precaution.

Therefore, setting an initial value is not supported.

Comment: I tried to assign a value to a file input field via the firebug console and I've got a security exception.. So yeah, It can't be done