# File field tag is not displaying value in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, filefield

I am using the following line in my .html.erb file

```
<@= file_field_tag 'file', :class => 'upload', value => 'index.html' %>
```

When it is rendered in the browser, it is not displaying the value 'index.html'.

Can someone help me in figuring out how to display the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set default value for a input file form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665058/set-default-value-for-a-input-file-form)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set a value on a file input in HTML. Therefore you can't do it via rails too.

Otherwise you could set the value in your page and submit the form via javascript and pluck files from your visitors computers.

Comment: Thanks Shadwell. what is the purpose of value => 'index.html' here?