# dynamic form not submitting file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to upload image to server in summernote. below script is success to submit the form but file not received at backend. am i doing something wrong here?

```
var edit = function() {
  $('.click2edit').summernote({
      focus: true,
      onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
            sendFile(files[0],editor,welEditable);
        }
      });
};
function sendFile(file,editor,welEditable) {

    alert(file.size);

    var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');

    $("body").append(iframe);
    alert("1");
    var form = $('#theuploadform');
    form.attr("action", "UploadServlet");
    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
    form.attr("target", "postiframe");
    form.attr("file", file);
    form.submit();
    alert("2");
    $("#postiframe").load(function () {
        iframeContents = $("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
        return iframeContent;
    });

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. got an work around for this issue. I changed the summernote code to return a wrapping form and them posted that form. It posted successfully. I have some issue in loading the uploaded image to editor. but i will start another thread for that. thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a default value to an HTML upload control.

You need to display the form for user choose the file, then you can post to server.

Some references:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp

[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

[Set default value for a input file form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665058/set-default-value-for-a-input-file-form)

Comment: @rkanawo Is there any work around for me. restriction is I will be getting file only at this position.

Comment: The only way you have to get files without user interaction is pre-installing softwares on client machine, running your page with an ActiveX control (only for IE) or Java Applet with some security troubles. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html