# Can we set a Value for <input type=file /> ? If Yes, please tell us to how to set it

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, file-upload

We are trying to set a value for input type 'file' but we are not able to achieve it. We know that there are some security issues but still we wanted to know whether it is possible to achieve it or not.

Comment: It's not possible, for security reasons indeed.

Comment: Is there any other options similar to that feature, I mean...we wanted to upload an image automatically.

Comment: If you could upload an image automatically, you could upload `/etc/passwd` automatically. Or a database file. Or the Windows Registry files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed due to security reason:

You can reference the following links:

[Set default value for a input file form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665058/set-default-value-for-a-input-file-form)

[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)