# How to open html file dialog with specified path from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, file, openfiledialog

I've input with `type="file"`, on clicking on button the file popup has been  opening it with default folder. like `C:/USERS/XYZ/Downloads`

But my requirement is, I want to open file popup with specified path(whatever I'll mentioned path  like `D:/Images/Stuff`). I googled a lot & don't having any luck on this.

Is there any way to open file popup with specified folder/path?

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/psko14e9/7/)

Any help/pointers would appreciate, Thanks

Comment: You can't, the path is user's choice.

Comment: @Teemu is there any alternative to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but a browser extension/add-on/plug-in might be capable of doing this.

Comment: @Teemu but as per my requirement, it should be work on cross browser like IE9, FF, chrome, etc.. so going for extension would not be a great idea.

Comment: Yes, I can understand that, but the fact is, that there's no way for a web-page to access the path.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for your time, you could add answer with bit explaination, I'll accept that :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the value. Because the html is not device specific. Meaning it can be seen on any browser of any machine. Please read this [Set default value for a input file form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665058/set-default-value-for-a-input-file-form)

Comment: My question is, could i set path to which i should open file dialog..is it possible?

Comment: @ThiefMaster is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: No. And I believe that's a good thing. How would any website know where I store the files I want to upload?