# How to instantiate a File object in Javascript with given file path

Tags: javascript, html

I get the full path of a file, how to instantiate a File object with this path ?

Comment: It's not possible. Otherwise, any page could try to load `/path/to/passwordFile.txt` without you even knowing it.

Comment: I thought you might use a file dialog but it seems you cannot pre set the path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467588/how-to-open-html-file-dialog-with-specified-path-from-javascript