# Change path of input file

Tags: html, file-io

I have a question. I am using an input[type=file] in a HTML form. Is it possible to change the path where dialogue is opened?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set default value for a input file form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665058/set-default-value-for-a-input-file-form)

Comment: Its not possible see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A duplicate question, but because it is a security risk and you can't be sure of the specific filesystem and OS of the user that is impossible.