# How to make web page remember last open file directory?

Tags: html, qml, qtwebengine, qt5.7

I have a Windows application based on Qt WebEngineView (in QML). There are web pages in my app. Some web page need user to select files using:

```
<input type="file" />
```

I want to know, is it possible for my app to remember the last directory user selected a file?

I have tried:

- Set value property to `<input>` in my web page, but it is not allowed by browser to set it programmatically, see [Set default value for a input file form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665058/set-default-value-for-a-input-file-form).
- Open my web pages in Chrome, Chrome can remember last directory. But in my app, every time it opens the directory where the app is installed.
- In native Open File Dialog, I can set an initial directory, but can I do the same for Open File Dialog in web pages?

I know this may be impossible. Any suggestions and workarounds are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebEngineView` element has a [signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html#fileDialogRequested-signal) for when the Web content requests a file dialog.

The `FileDialog` element has a [property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-filedialog.html#folder-prop) for setting (and getting) the folder.

So something along these lines should work

```
FileDialog {
    id: dialog

    property var request

    onRejected: request.dialogReject()

    onAccepted: {
        yourSavedFolder = folder;

        request.dialogAccept(files);
    }
}

WebEngineView {
    onFileDialogRequested: {
        request.accepted = true; // inhibit default dialog

        dialog.request = request;
        dialog.folder = yourSavedFolder;
        dialog.open()
    }
}
```

This is just a rough sketch, you'll also need to handle the open mode of the request object, etc.

Comment: Very helpful!   **Note:** **1.** `onFileDialogRequested` needs Qt 5.8. **2.** `request.dialogAccept(files);` should be `request.dialogAccept(fileUrl.toString());` (in single selection mode)