# Is it possible to convert an Image in IFormFile

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to store a model informations in my Data Base, this informations contain an image, so I created a simple view with some entrys, with a media picker button to pick it and an image witch display the picked one.
This is the button method and the store method:

```cs
 async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(new MediaPickerOptions
            {
                Title = "Please pick a photo"
            });

            if (result != null)
            {
                var stream = await result.OpenReadAsync();

                resultImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
            }
        }
  public async Task SaveMachine()

        {

            var machine = new Machine
            {
                Machine_Name = nom.Text,
                Machine_Qr = qr.Text,
                Files = resultImage

            };

            await _rest.AddMachine(machine);

            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
```

But I can't create **Files = resultImage** because the Files in the model is in IFormFile.

Comment: Save the `IFormFile` to your disk instead, and save the path to the file in the database.

Comment: I used asp.net core and I created an api to store both the image and the image path in the sqlServer

Comment: @Jason can you have a look ?

Comment: `resultImage` is an **Image control**, not image data.  You need to send the data to the server.  Based on the code you posted I'm not sure what the best way to do that is.

Comment: no the resultImage is the name of the image in the view

Comment: it is the name of the **Image control** in your UI.  An `Entry` is a UI control that contains a string, it is not the string itself.  Likewise, an `Image` is a UI control that contains image data, but it is not the data itself.

Comment: if `Files` is an `IFormFile`, then it has a constructor that takes a stream.  You would use the same stream used to create the `Image` to create the `FormFile`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245692/discussion-between-gazdallah-amira-and-jason).

Comment: keep a reference to the stream (or a byte[] of the data) when you select the image, then use that reference again when creating the FormFile

Comment: I didn't inderstand what you mean by "keep a reference to the stream (or a byte[] of the data)", can you more explain ?

Comment: The `Files` and `resultImage` are different type of variable, so you can try to get the instance of `Files` from a stream, such as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477717/how-to-create-an-iformfile-image-file-and-send-it-to-input-element-in-view).