# HTML form file set value

Tags: html, forms, file

If I do the following, the browse text box still cannot see
C:/hello world/test.txt.

```
<input type="file" name="fileName" value="C:/hello world/test.txt" size=80>
```

Any ideas? and workarounds to this problem? thanks!!

Comment: You cannot do this. It would allow websites to steal our files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot set a default value for the file field, I would assume this is a security feature

Comment: You are correct. If we could set it in script you could grab any file from the client machine if you knew the path.