# Filling in input type=file

Tags: html, input, tags

I know that prefilling of `<input type = file />` tags in HTML is not allowed due to security reasons. But is there any `automated` way through `scripts` of any sorts to fill the field with a prespecified file `(by the user, and not the server`) in an automatic way?

Comment: didn't got your question, what do you mean by pre-filling here?

Comment: There might be workaround solutions. could you explain in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: wouldn't that defeat the purpose for which this is not allowed ? The only way is that the user clicks the browse and selects the file (*since the file input refers to local files, the user is obligated to go through the file selection window*) ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Comment: what i am trying to do is submit a form with a file upload required, now is there a way by either converting the html doc into raw form or otherwise to do this automatically?? since it is the user sending the file path so i think the security threat is overruled???

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible (for good reasons), and is in fact considered a security issue if it were possible to do so.  Imagine if a server could automatically select a file on the user's computer to upload.  Scary, huh?

You can see that Microsoft addressed this in a [bug report.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/266087)