# Preload file into input type="file"

Tags: input, field

I am wondering if there is a way to have a file input field start up with a file pre-loaded in to it.

For example I have a test file on my server - 'test.txt'

When the user opens the page, I want to have test.txt already loaded in to the input field so all they have to do is fill out the text fields and hit submit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Answer (score 2):

Imagine it was possible. Then you could hide the input field using css and steal any file you wanted ;-)

Comment: I know lol I realized it pretty quickly after I had posted. It would be quite dangerous

Answer (score -1):

Apparently a large security risk and browsers prevent against performing such a task.

Comment: If you are going to imply something, it is important to back it up with some links