# Security Exception 0x80530012 when passing jQuery with attached file. Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, angularjs, browser

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Exception... "The operation is insecure." code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)" location: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js Line: 2257"]
```

I've tried to look up the code but I can't find what the exception is. Simply put I have an Angularjs object being passed that looks like:

```
replyForm = {

    body: someString,

    // Gets the file from some input
    fileAttachment: event.target.files[0]

}
```

And I have a function that recieves the replyForm object and tries to pass it into some function like so:

```
var exe = function (replyForm){

    //This is the line that causes my mozilla security exception to go off
    sendForm(replyForm);
};

var sendForm = function(replyForm){

    // This is when I get the security exception
    $('input.fileInput').val(replyForm.fileAttachment);
};
```

If you want to see how my fileAttachment gets set in Angularjs, please refer bellow:

```
.directive('ngFile',function(){
            return {
            scope: {
                ngFile: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, el, attrs){
                el.bind('change', function(event){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        scope.ngFile = event.target.files[0];
                    });

                });
            }
        };
    });
```

It would be great if anyone could tell me what was wrong with passing an object with a file attached to one of it's properties. Though it seems there is an issue with jQuery trying to do something to the dom which creates some security exception.

Comment: For reference: 0x80530012 is `NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you peel away the layers, the line you are referring to is trying to set `input.value` on a file input field. This isn't possible for [security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017237/785541). The value of a file input field has to be selected by the user, it cannot be set by JavaScript.

If you need to upload a file, you don't need a file upload field for that - a [`FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)  can handle that for you. Something along these lines should work:

```
var sendForm = function(replyForm){
  var fd = new FormData($("#myform"));
  fd.append("fileInput", replyForm.fileAttachment);
  ...
  $.ajax({..., data: fd});
```

`FormData` is supported starting with Firefox 4, Chrome 7 and IE 10.