# How to duplicate file input value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Is there any way to duplicate the file input value? in this case, if i have including a file in fileA input, the value of fileB is following fileA values, is there anybody know how to do this?

```
<input type="file" name="fileA" />
<input type="file" name="fileB" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: **This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not allowed to set the value of a file input element due to security issues.

Comment: are you sure there is no way?

Comment: Yes, there's no way to achieve it. You can check some same threads with regards to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html