# How to set jQuery ajax response as input type="file" value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to set jQuery ajax response as `input type="file"` value for updation purpose?
Here I get question response as `byte[]` array. How do I set this to file type?

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'viewQuestion.html',
    data: ({
        questionId: id
    }),
    success: function(responseData) {
        $('#updateQstn').val(responseData.question);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" value="Browse" name="updateQstn"
        accept="image/*" id="updateQstn" />
```

Comment: What for do you want to do this? I doubt it's possible.

Comment: for updation purpose i want to set value to this conrol.unless i throw exception.
if user update image change value to new value. i can do that.
if user doesnot want to change it ,it remain same value.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html) question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input) one. Yes, they are about file URLs, but I have never heard about setting `input type="file"` value as byte array.

Comment: thnx Regent it is not possible.