# how to set text box value to upload filename using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, file, upload, textbox

how to set textbox value based on uploaded filename value.for example i'm upload file like test.zip same value affect in text box the below code am try but not get solution?

```
var filename= document.getElementById("file").value;
    <form>
     File: <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
     Upload File : <input type="text" value="'+filename+'"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Comment: U need to use the files attribute to get the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some thing like this

```
  <script>
   function setfilename(val)
  {
    var fileName = val.substr(val.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, val.length);
   document.getElementById("filename").value = fileName;
  }
</script>
    <form>
     File: <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="setfilename(this.value);"/>
     Upload File : <input type="text"  id="filename"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get names of files by accessing files object of fileUpload like

```
document.getElementById("file").files[0].name
```

Assign this value to your text field `onChange` event of `fileInput` like this

```
document.getElementById("filename").value = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
```

will set first file name into your field with id `filename`

Getting value attribute of file input directly will get you fake file path like `C:\fakepath\yourfilename.ext`

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen `onchange` event of the file field and when it occurs you write the value to another text input.

```
var file = document.getElementById("file");
file.onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('filename').value = file.value;
};
```

Where I set an id for the text field also:

```
Upload File : <input type="text" id="filename" value="'+filename+'"/>
```

However note, that the value you can retrieve from file input is *not real* but has a fake path due to security considerations. If you need only filename part of the full path you can split it by `/` character ad take the last piece.