# Pass hidden values in html file type

Tags: php, file-upload

I am not sure about that i'm thinking in right way or not.
Is it possible to pass one default value of file  in file type in html . like below

```
 <input type="file" name="bulk_images_<?php echo $OrderProduct->orders_products_id?>'[]" value="<?php echo $OrderProduct->bulk_images; ?>" />
```

So that i will get it in

> $_FILES[name]

attribute

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Comment: No you can't do this, impossible to set default file

Comment: ok. Now only i saw the same question in stack overflow. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

try

```
bulk_images_[<?php echo $OrderProduct->orders_products_id?>]
```

Comment: Wrong, he want put value in array with dynamic increment key not fixed key