# Is it possible to set static value input type="file"

Tags: jquery, html

is it possible to set a static value for input type= file

```
 <input type="file" id="myfile" value="empty" name="myfilename">

 $('[name=myfilenmae]').val();
```

it returns ''

but need to get

empty

Comment: `$('[name=myfilenmae]').val() || 'empty'`

Comment: `''` is an empty string. If you want to check for that and convert it to `'empty'` for some reason, you can always use an `if` statement. (`($('[name=myfilename]').val() || 'empty')` is shorter here, I guess.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot preset (or dynamically set) the value of a file field. Allowing that would raise a huge security risk, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017237/2057919).