# using single function how to call two different input fields

Tags: javascript

Hi in the below code I am going to upload the image using following java script function.for the first input working fine.In the same way how to call second input field when I am passing the id it's got changes the first one and second one images are displaying same.

**html**

```
 <div class="person_pic">
    <label>Please upload your photo</label><input  type='file' name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div class="person_pic">
    <label>Please upload your family photo</label>
    <input  type='file' name="image" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah1" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);        
    }
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();    
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah1')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(150)
                .height(200);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to do it. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev that is not question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the id of the img element that you want to change.As you are using $('#blah') for both the function call , hence both the time same image is being displayed.You can do this:

```
<script>
        function readURL(input,x) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                x = '#'+x;
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $(x)
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
</script>
<div class="person_pic">
    <label>Please upload your photo</label>
    <input  type='file' name="image" onchange="readURL(this,'blah');" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
<div class="person_pic">
    <label>Please upload your family photo</label>
    <input  type='file' name="image" onchange="readURL(this,'blah1');" />
    <img id="blah1" src="#" alt="your image" />
</div>
```

Comment: this answer only I am looking