# on editing file upload field is blank

Tags: image, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2x. I have a problem in my edit page image upload field. Everytime  when i try to edit my profile page , it shows image upload field blank.Other fields information are remains same as fill in the add form of profile but the image field is not enable to retrieve stored image. I am  new to cakephp,if anyone knows how i can retrieve image? plz help! And i also want to know how i can store more than one image and also check the same image is not uploading twice. Thanks! Here is my image upload code->

```
 // File upload function in Model.php
       public $validate = array( 
         'image' => array(
        'uploadError' => array(
            'rule' => 'uploadError',
            'message' => 'Something went wrong with the file upload',
            'required' => FALSE,
            'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
        ),
        // http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-   validation.html#Validation::mimeType

        // custom callback to deal with the file upload
        'imageOne' => array(
            'rule' => 'imageOne',
            'message' => 'Something went wrong processing your file',
            'required' => FALSE,
            'allowEmpty' => TRUE,
            'last' => TRUE,
        ),
    ),
   );


public function imageOne($check=array()) {
  // deal with uploaded file
   if (!empty($check['image']['tmp_name'])) {

      // check file is uploaded
      if (!is_uploaded_file($check['image']['tmp_name'])) {
        return FALSE;
      }

    // build full filename
     $filename = WWW_ROOT . $this->uploadDir . DS .   Inflector::slug(pathinfo($check['image']['name'],   PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'.'.pathinfo($check['image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // @todo check for duplicate filename
 /* if (!file_exists($check['image']['tmp_name'],$filename)) {
   echo "Sorry, file already exists.";

    }*/
    // try moving file
    if (!move_uploaded_file($check['image']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
        return FALSE;

    // file successfully uploaded
    } else {
        // save the file path relative from WWW_ROOT e.g.     uploads/example_filename.jpg
        $this->data[$this->alias]['filepath'] = str_replace(DS, "/",     str_replace(WWW_ROOT, "", $filename) );
    }
}

return TRUE;
 }


   public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
  // a file has been uploaded so grab the filepath
  if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['filepath'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['image'] = $this->data[$this->alias]    ['filepath'];
}


  // Controller.php

  public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->CollegeProfile->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid college profile'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $this->request->data['CollegeProfile']['user_id'] = $this->Auth-  >user('id');
        $this->request->data['CollegeProfile']['id'] = $id;
        if ($this->CollegeProfile->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The college profile has been saved.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-success'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The college profile could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'default', array('class' => 'alert alert-danger'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('CollegeProfile.' . $this->CollegeProfile->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->CollegeProfile->find('first', $options);
    }
    $this->loadModel('State');
    $states = $this->State->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('states'));
}

 //Edit.ctp
 <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo $this ->Form->input('image',array('class'=>'form-control','type'=>'file'));?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this.

See related question: [Dynamically set value of a file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input).

> Most browsers block against setting the value attribute on input type file for security reasons so that you can't upload a file without the user's input.

However, in the interests of showing the user what they last selected, you can do something like this;

```
<?php
// edit.ctp
if (!empty($this->request->data['Model']['image'])) {
    $label = "Current file: " . $this->request->data['Model']['image'];
} else {
    $label = __("Select file");
}
echo $this->Form->input('Model.image', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => $label));
```

Comment: yes,@Robmcvey ,My edit form includes the type => file.

Comment: above all works fine,my problem is after adding a profile,when i click on edit,my file uploads field are blanks,i am able to reupload files from my edit form but the main problem is after adding when i go on edit  my file upload field atleast shows the name of the upload files that i upload in my add form-it shoudn't be blank.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, instead you could fetch the data before the save,compare if the field value is blank and re fill with the array you fetched before.
For example

```
$data=$this->Option->findById(1);

//pic slide1

$slide1=$this->image($this->request->data['Option']['slide1']);(this is the upload)
if($slide1){ $this->request->data['Option']['slide1']=$slide1; }else{$this->request->data['Option']['slide1']=$data['Option']['slide1'];}
```

In this case I have an "image function" that returns the name of the upload, so if the name is empty I set the request data pic1 value with the $data array value I fetched before.