# HTML input type file set filepath destination

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, input

I have an input type file like so:

```
 <label for="rendering">Rendering</label><input type="file" name="rendering" id="rendering" />
```

Is there away to set the folder destination so when the dialog box appears, its set to a folder ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically set value of a file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)

Comment: How do you know what folders user has?