# Laravel Form - load file field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-form, laravel-filesystem

I have a file field in my form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('pdf', 'PDF Template') !!}
    {!! Form::file('pdf') !!}

    <a href="{{route('download_pdf', ['id' => $template->id])}}">Download current PDF</a>
</div>
```

I'm using the [laravelcollective](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html) package to create my forms.

Now on my **edit page** I would like to load the current file (set the file field). But how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not set value of the file input.

Related questions:

- [Dynamically set value of a file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input)
- [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-)

Comment: its not best practices to mention only reference link... please provide some solution or weather add the question to duplicate or something other moderator as per you references.