# Setting value of file input programmatically

Tags: javascript, input

I have already read up on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input), and know that it is impossible due to security restrictions, however I have a few more specific questions about this.

1. What about for a machine that is not connected to the internet? Are there any chrome settings that I could set in order to allow this?
2. What would happen if I were to change the input type to `text` and then add the file path and proceed to submit the form? will it work for selecting a file to run? I cannot test this because I am working with a router UI through HTML and while it may seem like it is working when I hit submit I can't tell if it is actually changing anything

Comment: Setting a text input to a file path is not going to submit a file.

Comment: @epascarello ok, so that at least answers the second part of my question. I also tried changing the type to text, and then back to file again, but it just gets rid of the input value

Comment: @epascarello what if I create a new file input element, is it possible to set like a default value for it or something?

Comment: Unless there is some browser config you can set, I doubt it. Even the html5 api requires user to select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input type="file">` doesn't allow you to set the `value` programmatically but it must be the user who locates the file to upload. Thus, **you can't turn your input into a `type="text"`, set a path and turn the so-called input into `type="file"` again and hold the `value`**.

> What would happen if I were to change the input type to text and then
>   add the file path and proceed to submit the form? will it work for
>   selecting a file to run?

It would send the file path instead of the file.