# Set file input field value (file path) programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input

I know this is a bit similar question like this
[Setting value of file input programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768057/setting-value-of-file-input-programmatically)

Note: I am wondering how this below plugin achieved this solution. Even though in each forum over internet saying that setting file input field path not possible programmatically.

Anyone ever set file input field value (file path) programmatically?

It works fine if user click and select a file but the goal is not to open the dialogue box for file selection. Aim is to set the file input field value in javascript/jquery.

this extension is doing this, they target to automate job application.
https://simplify.jobs/

We want to do this same functionality but setting file input field value (which is a file path) is a challenge at the moment. Any easy work around will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside of a browser extension, or just on a web page?

Comment: Extensions are allowed to do lots of things that regular web pages can't.

Comment: yes i am trying to achieve this in a chrome extension, how can i set the file input field value javascript/jquery?

Comment: @Barmar any insights on this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the specific way they're doing it. You'll have to reverse-engineer the extension.