# Choosing the path of a file directly in script?

Tags: javascript, html

Alright, so here's my little problem. 
I am trying to read a file directly from the script in JavaScript, but I have no idea how.

In order to get my file in a variable, I use this:

```
  function readSingleFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0]; 
    if (!file) 
      return; 


    var reader = new FileReader();


    reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result; 
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);}


    document.getElementById('file-input')
    .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

with this HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
```

The main idea is, how do I choose the path of 'file' variable directly in script? Thank you so much!

Comment: The user needs to pick the file, you can not select it with code. That would be a big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

> The main idea is, how do I choose the path of 'file' variable directly in script?

You can't. It would be a security violation to allow JavaScript code to read any file it wanted from the user's system. That's why if you look at the "path" you get from the `input type="file"`, you'll see a fake path (but likely a real filename) like (on Windows) `C:\fakepath\realFileName.txt`.

This question is closely related to, though perhaps not *quite* a duplicate of, [*Dynamically set value of a file input*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017224/dynamically-set-value-of-a-file-input).