# How to remove the validation if the file type is not empty

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-validate

I am uploading the profile pic and banner image in the folder and name into the database.
I have added the below 2 files and inserted them into the database and folder.

[image]

Now, I don't want to update the file but when I submit then I am getting the validation error message. I know my file type is empty and I am previewing the image.

I have to set the validation if the file is empty.

[image]

```js
$("form[name='myprofile']").validate({
  rules: {
    file1: {
      required: true,
      extension: "png|jpe?g",
    },
    file2: {
      required: true,
      extension: "png|jpe?g",
    }

  },
  messages: {
    file1: {
      extension: "Please upload jpeg or png image",
    },
    file2: {
      extension: "Please upload jpeg or png image",
    }
  },



  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}
```

```html
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="myprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myprofile">
  <input type="file" name="file1"><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="file1" value="<?php echo $info['file1'];?>">
  <!--store image name image-->
  <img src="assets/images/<?php echo $info['file1'];?>">
  <!--Preview image-->
  <input type="file" name="file2"><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="file2" value="<?php echo $info['file2'];?>">
  <!--store image name image-->
  <img src="assets/images/<?php echo $info['file2'];?>">
  <!--Preview image-->

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can dynamically change the rules and rule parameters using the `.rules()` method.  Please refer to documentation on website and examples on SO.

Answer (score 0):

As value of filename is store inside `hidden` input you can check if the hidden input related to particular file has value or not depending on this you set `required` attribute true or false.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$("form[name='myprofile']").validate({
  rules: {
    file1: {
      required: function() {
        //check if the hidden input related to file is empty if yes return true else false..
        return $("[type=file][name=file1]").nextAll("[type=hidden]:first").val() == ""
      },
      extension: "png|jpe?g",
    },
    file2: {
      required: function() {
        //same here
        return $("[type=file][name=file2]").nextAll("[type=hidden]:first").val() == ""
      },
      extension: "png|jpe?g",
    }

  },
  messages: {
    file1: {
      extension: "Please upload jpeg or png image",
    },
    file2: {
      extension: "Please upload jpeg or png image",
    }
  },



  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="file"] {
  padding-bottom: 45px;
}
```

```html
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="myprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myprofile">
  <input type="file" name="file1">
  <br />
  <input type="hidden" name="file1" value="<?php echo $info['file1'];?>">
  <img src="assets/images/<?php echo $info['file1'];?>">
  <input type="file" name="file2"><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="file2" value="">
  <img src="assets/images/<?php echo $info['file2'];?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is this the right way to use the hidden input field?

Comment: you are talking about your html i.e : the way you have store file-name ?

Comment: Yes, Is this the right way to use it? I mean instead of hidden field can we show the value in the file type

Comment: no you can't show value inside [file type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1017237/10606400) like that .

Comment: Yes, I checked. Thank you for the link. I checked your snippet. I am not getting the validation for both files.

Comment: Yes , because in my demo html code i have added `value=""` for second file just for testing  so its showing this field is required for second file type . Sorry if i didn't understood your question :)